# ULA's ACES upper stage with IVF - Why are they using internal combustion engines?

Tags: power, cryogenics, upper-stage, ula, fuel-cell

I recently read out about ULA's ACES (Advanced Cryogenic Evolved Stage) upper stage with IVF (Integrated Vehicle Fluids), which crazy as it sounds, has two six-cylinder engines developed by Roush that use the boiled-off H<sub>2</sub> and O<sub>2</sub> as fuel. These engines provide pressurized fluid for the thrusters and fuel tanks, and generate electrical power, displacing the batteries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Cryogenic_Evolved_Stage

Supposedly, this allows the upper stage to remain powered for a much longer period of time (that normally would deplete batteries).

This idea strikes me as pretty cool but crazy sounding (up there with ULA catching engines for re-use with a helicopter, but that's another topic). A fuel cell stack seems like a better fit for these requirements and have been used in space applications for a long time. What are the benefits of using internal combustion engine over a fuel cell? I know ULA has been working on the IVF for some time now. Have advances in battery technology made IVF obsolete?

Comment: It doesn't, I mixed up my acronyms. Fixed.

Comment: Burning hydrogen with pure 100 % oxygen might be too hot for a piston engine, a fuel rich mixture may be needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What a fantastic question! I learned a lot researching this one.

> The use of a simple piston-in-cylinder engine on an ultra high
>   performance in-space stage seems to be out of place in a technology
>   landscape dominated by high speed turbomachines, fuel cells and solar
>   panels.
>
> Didn’t we move into the jet age? How could this possibly be a good
>   solution? At the outset we, too, felt like we had wandered into a
>   technological twilight zone. **The key to understanding is that the high
>   workload task for the system is not producing electricity or turning a
>   shaft to drive a hydraulic pump.** Tank pressurization is the dominant
>   activity and it demands the delivery of enthalpy to the main tank
>   ullage spaces – whatever the source. The IVF engine is superior to
>   other lower temperature systems in that its waste heat is of high
>   quality and is sufficient to turn cryogenic liquids into vapor. **Half
>   of the inefficiency of a heat engine is put directly to work pushing
>   enthalpy into a working fluid for pressurization and the remainder is
>   used to produce the small amount of thrust required to settle
>   propellants.**
>
> A turbine could be used for such an application but it would be
>   exquisitely small with extremely high rotating speeds to produce only
>   20kW with low density hydrogen as the working fluid. Provisions for
>   heat and shaft power extraction could be made but the overall
>   developmental complexity of cooling, lubrication, ignition, control
>   and power take off at this very low power level seemed daunting
>   compared to the IC engine. The use of such small turbines on ground
>   based installations is virtually unheard of. Virtually a whole new
>   technology would have to be developed at substantial cost and risk.
>
> Similarly a fuel cell could be used to drive IVF with the advantage of
>   no high speed machinery and an extensive history of spaceflight.
>   Proton Exchange Membrane (PEM) cells have shown a tremendous amount of
>   promise in recent years. **However, 20kW is a relatively large fuel cell
>   for flight applications and because all power is produced as
>   electricity (as compared to perhaps 10% for the IC engine) it must be
>   converted via motors to shaft power with their attendant switching
>   systems and losses.** This grows the fuel cell to address conversion
>   efficiencies. Reactants are only consumed at a mixture ratio of 8 –
>   which is generally insufficient for regenerative cooling so unless a
>   bulky and costly radiator system is employed a larger flow of hydrogen
>   must be brought to the fuel cell to maintain thermal stasis. **From a
>   consumables standpoint the fuel cell loses its advantage over the IC
>   engine. The PEM cell efficiency is founded on low operating
>   temperature which produces condensed liquid water which must be
>   disposed of without providing any benefit for vehicle settling.** In
>   general, the use of a fuel cell system would be most advantageous for
>   crewed vehicles where the water produced has a strong positive
>   influence on vehicle mass. **For cryogenic propulsive stages the cost
>   differential between IC engines and fuel cells likely favors the
>   former.**

United Launch Alliance, [Development Status of an Integrated Propulsion and Power System for Long Duration Cryogenic Spaceflight](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/extended-duration/development-status-of-an-integrated-propulsion-and-power-system-for-long-duration-cryogenic-spaceflight-2012.pdf). Emphasis mine.

In short: fuel cells are too expensive & don't produce enough heat.

Comment: Sort of funny how the answer is "it wasn't inefficient enough to be very efficient".

Comment: Funny how something you'd be *craving* for in a crewed mission is a true burden when uncrewed.